# Circular List Traversal Engine

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, scheduling, circular-dependency

I want to traverse a circular linked list `(v1->v2->v3)` in a given input order, lets say like

`{v1,v3,v2,v2,v1,v3,v2,v1,v1,v3,v2,v2,v1,v2,v3}`.

I wrote the below program as test for 3 nodes and would like to scale incrementally for 8, 64, 512, 4096, etc. nodes.

My idea of implementation requires the below program to run solely on an `Abstract State Machine` which only accepts the below functions as input for processing. I basically want to minimise the loop count of `engine_spin_at_gear()` while traversing. I may be on a `non-blocking` mode for using such an insane `abstraction` to mimic/virtualize `process-execution` as an `engine-spin` with unit of measurement as rpm, but I would really like suggestions on debugging the `engine_spin_at_gear()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MILES 15

struct package
{
        // ... other members data ...
        struct package *next;
}*v1, *v2, *v3;

int input_arr[MILES] = {1,3,2,2,1,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,2,3};

struct package *base(struct package *_vN)
{
        if (_vN)
                return _vN;
        else
                return NULL;
}

struct package *deliver(struct package *_vNP)
{
        if (_vNP)
                return base(_vNP->next);
        else
                return NULL;
}

void shift_gear(struct package *_feed)
{
        _feed->next = NULL;
}

struct package *engine_spin_at_gear(struct package *_init_cycle0, int countSession)
{
        while (countSession--) {
                shift_gear(_init_cycle0);
                return deliver(base(_init_cycle0));
        }
        return NULL;
}

struct package *journey(struct package *_current_frame, int _start, int _end)
{
        int rpm = (_end > _start)?_end-_start:_start-_end;
        if (rpm)
                return engine_spin_at_gear(_current_frame, rpm);
        else
                return v1;
}

struct package *ignition_phase(int _batteryS, int _chargedL)
{
        return journey(v1, _batteryS, _chargedL);
}


void transmit_in_order(int*input_arr)
{
        struct package *v6;
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<MILES-1; i++) {
                v6 = ignition_phase(input_arr[i], input_arr[i+1]);
                printf("%p\n", v6);
        }
}

int main()
{
        v1 = malloc(sizeof(struct package));
        v2 = malloc(sizeof(struct package));
        v3 = malloc(sizeof(struct package));

        v1->next = v2;
        v2->next = v3;
        v3->next = v1;

        printf("v1=%p\tv2=%p\tv3=%p\n", v1, v2, v3);
        transmit_in_order(input_arr);
        return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following output when I ran my program's GCC executable on Linux.

```
v1=0x918b008    v2=0x918b018    v3=0x918b028
(nil)
(nil)
0x918b008
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
0x918b008
(nil)
(nil)
0x918b008
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
```

Or, do I need to change `shift_gear()` function? Can I optimise it more while keeping the `scalability-factor` intact? Thanks in advance. If I want to put all these functions in `C++` as `Class Engine` and `Class Gearbox`, can you show me a prototype?

Comment: The return 'return deliver(base(_init_cycle0));' inside the while loop inside engine_spin_at_gear looks suspect. It will always return on the first time through the loop.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Even when I change above to `return deliver(_init_cycle0)` the output remains unchanged. Strange!!

Comment: Move the closing while `}` to after `shift_gear(_init_cycle0);` instead of where it is.

Comment: @ayyker The output seems to be immune to any such changes. Looping `shift_gear(_init_cycle0)` has no effect on the o/p.

Comment: Actually, not immune.  I get different values.  Your values (in OP configuration) are as shown, right after I fixed the index issue (MILES-1), I got another set of values, then after moving `}`, I got another set.  See my answer edit for images.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization aside, you have a problem with input_arr:

```
int input_arr[MILES] = {1,3,2,2,1,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,2,3}; //has 15 elements
```

While following loop requires 16:

```
for (i=0; i<MILES-1; i++) { //[edited] so i goes from 0 to 13
        v6 = ignition_phase(input_arr[i], input_arr[i+1]);  //otherwise, i goes to 14, +1 == 15 - 1 too big
        printf("%p\n", v6);
}
```

Either create a bigger array, or stop the loop 1 increment earlier.

Regarding this code:

```
struct package *engine_spin_at_gear(struct package *_init_cycle0, int countSession)
{
        while (countSession--) {
                shift_gear(_init_cycle0);  // }
                return deliver(base(_init_cycle0));
        }
        return NULL;
}  //move this one to after shift_gear(_init_cycle0);
```

Should the closing while loop  `}` be moved to where indicated at comment?  (per your's and Charlie's observation)  If you keep the return statement in there , you will never make it past the first loop.

Output changes according to minor changes to code:
After changing for `for (i=0; i<MILES; i++) {` to `for (i=0; i<MILES-1; i++) {`
[image]

After changing

```
while (countSession--) {
        shift_gear(_init_cycle0);
        return deliver(base(_init_cycle0));
}
```

to:

```
while (countSession--) {
        shift_gear(_init_cycle0);}
        return deliver(base(_init_cycle0));
```

// }

[image]

So, it appears there is some effect, but I am not sure how to interpret this output.  i.e. what significance these changes mean.

Comment: Only the pointer values have changed but still the output is displaying only `v1` node values along with NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You mention scaling to larger number of items, here is some parts that scale to 100,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct package_s
{
    // ... other members data ...
    struct package_s* next;
} package; //being lazy, I avoid typing struct everywhere...

#define HOWMANY (100)
package* v[HOWMANY];

#define MILES 15
int input_arr[MILES] = {1,3,2,2,1,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,2,3};

package*
journey(package* _current_frame, int _start, int _end)
{
    int rpm = (_end > _start) ? (_end-_start) : (_start-_end);
    if (rpm)
        return engine_spin_at_gear(_current_frame, rpm);
    else
        return v[0];
}

package*
ignition_phase(int _batteryS, int _chargedL)
{
    return journey(v[0], _batteryS, _chargedL);
}
```

And this fixes the addressing off the end of input_arr (maybe you want to wrap back to zero?)

```
void
transmit_in_order(int*input_arr)
{
    package *v6;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<MILES-2; i++) {
        v6 = ignition_phase(input_arr[i], input_arr[i+1]);
        printf("%p\n", v6);
    }
}
```

And the main for configurable number of `v[n]`,

```
int main()
{
    int ndx;
    for(ndx=0; ndx<HOWMANY; ++ndx)
    {
        v[ndx] = malloc(sizeof(package));
    }

    for(ndx=0; ndx<HOWMANY; ++ndx)
    {
        v[ndx]->next = v[(ndx+1)%HOWMANY];
        printf("v[%d]=%p\t", ndx, v[ndx]);
    }
    printf("\n", ndx, v[ndx]);

    transmit_in_order(input_arr);
    return 0;
}
```